# templating in nodejs confused about several things

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mustache

When it comes to templating my understanding is that you can do several things:

1. Serve static pages.
2. Pre Compile everything (jade to html) once and then serve the same thing to all.
3. At every request render everything and then serve.
4. Render static parts ahead of time (when app starts) and render dynamic parts at request.
5. Serve vanilla html and render dynamic part at request.
6. Send vanilla html + template and library(engine) and render at client.

What i want to do is number 5 and if not then 4. I don't want to rewrite all html, css etc. For the sake of just templating. I want to stick to html. But for part that needs to be dynamic i'd like templating. However if in case that this is not possible. I'd like to be able at least precompile the static part of the page and then compile user specific (dynamic) part at request.

I was looking into jade, but i can't figure out how would i do that? Is there a way, there should be, that i can type jade within html so only parts are dynamic are done in jade. I was told to compile jade, then append it to vanilla html. This is not ok. Because it requires me manually piece together html which isn't viable solution if you have lots of html and pages.

I hope everything is clear..if not leave a comment.

Comment: could it be there is templating engine that gives what i want. I looked into ejs too. But i just didn't like it's verbose syntax and extra functions.

Comment: Why not just use a templating language that primarily uses HTML, Mustache for example? Maybe see if http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/ has something you like.

Comment: That's what suggested jade..how do i tell it to find me html based templating language.

Comment: Feel free to just click through to each option and read its documentation to see if it's something you'd like to use.

Comment: or ask people here like this who have been through these decisions before..especially considering i have spent like whole day on it.

Comment: beside for even html based templates...at every different request html that's not need to be looked over again and again drags in with dynamic html, as far as i know with jade you can include pure html files. But it means if i have file structure with 20 dynamic parts then to completely avoid dragging in static html i would have to slice html into 40 parts.

Comment: For what you're trying to do, you just create a template for your page.  That template will have both the static HTML you want and the dynamic portions.  Then, you "render" the template upon each request and the rendering action puts the dynamic part in with the static parts to make a complete page.  Any decent nodejs implementation of a templating engine will compile the template once and then cache the compiled template so it will be faster to render it (e.g. process the dynamic portions) upon future requests.  I personally use Handlebars, but many will do this.